# Check AJAX response data before taking action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call to a PHP script that returns either the content of a Bootstrap3 modal, or an HTML form.

PHP code - (ajax.php):

```
if ($numLegs == 1) {
    echo $formData;
} else {
    echo $modalContent;
}
```

If it returns $formData, I want to display the form data, and if it returns the $modalContent, I want to display the modal. 
How can I check the response data before deciding what action to take?

Here is my code so far - it displays the modal window with the $modalContent from the AJAX call. But can I first check the AJAX response data before deciding what action to take?

```
<script>
// By default, modal window is hidden
$('#myModal').modal({show:false});

// This is the function when the button is clicked
function ajaxCall() {

  var date = $('.pull-info').parent().prev().prev().children(':input').val();
  var num = $('.pull-info').parent().prev().children(':input').val();

    $.get( 
      "ajax.php",
      { date: date, 
        num: num },
      function(response) {
        // HOW DO I CHECK THE RESPONSE BEFORE TAKING THE RELEVANT ACTION???!
        $(".modalBody").html(response);
        $(".modalHeader").text(num);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
      }
    );
 }
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: in response itself set one more variable which says which one to use. something like `if(response.type=='modal'){//modal code}`

Comment: How `$numLegs` is set? Is it set regarding `num`client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would return a `json` string, with a flag for what type of content it is:

```
if ($numLegs == 1) {
    echo json_encode(['type' => 'form', 'content' => $formData]);
} else {
    echo json_encode(['type' => 'modal', 'content' => $modalContent]);
}
```

And then in your js:

```
$.getJSON("ajax.php", { date: date, num: num },
    function(response) {
        // HOW DO I CHECK THE RESPONSE BEFORE TAKING THE RELEVANT ACTION???!
        if (response.type == 'form') {
            $('.form').html(response.content);
        } else if (response.type == 'modal') {
            $(".modalBody").html(response.content);
            $(".modalHeader").text(num);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what ever format the response data is.

if the format is `JSON` you can directly compare the condition that you are looking for.

Otherwise try to parse it to JSON and apply the same conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you must return `JSON` data from server instead raw HTML. So your PHP code will be:

```
if ($numLegs == 1) {
    echo json_encode(array('html' => $formData, 'type' => 'form'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('html' => $modalContent, 'type' => 'modal'));
}
```

And in javascript side you can check `response.type` and show what you want. And `response.html` will contain HTML for modal or form

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna want to return JSON from your PHP. You can do this by running `json_encode` on a PHP array. Like so:

```
$responseArray = array();

if ($numLegs == 1) {
    $responseArray['data'] = $formData;
    $responseArray['type'] = 'form';
}
else {
    $responseArray['data'] = $modalContent;
    $responseArray['type'] = 'modal';
}

echo $responseArray;
```

From there, you want your javascript to detect the `type` parameter that is passed into the response:

```
$.get( 
  "ajax.php",
  { date: date, 
    num: num },
  function(response) {

    if ( response.type === 'form' ) {
        // do form stuff

    }
    else if ( response.type === 'modal' ) {
        // do modal stuff

    }

  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$.get(´ajax.php´).then(function(res){
 console.log(res)
})
```